# Port asm in Xcode 4.5

Tags: assembly, xcode4.5

Hope someone can help me out with this.
I never learned ASM so I can't do anything with this snippet. But I need it for processing and it worked fine for me (was part of a code snippet i used for VC++ programming earlier, now I'm on Xcode 4.5), so I don't know how it exactly works.

I read on some posts, that I have to set quotes. BUT: Where?

```
    asm(
    fld newVal
    fabs
    fcom oldMax
    fstsw ax
    sahf
    jna else_
    fstp oldMax; // |newVal| > oldMax; pop to oldMax
    jmp endif_
else_:
    ffree st(0)
endif_:
     );
```

I tried quotes on every line, on beginning and ending. Don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asm` is the Visual Studio syntax, GCC and Clang use `__asm__` for assembly language. Your code also appears to be in Intel syntax, GCC usually uses a slightly different syntax called AT&T. You can find out more at the [GCC ASM how to](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3).

Something like this would be a good place to get started:

```
__asm__(
"fld %0\n"
"fabs\n"
"fcom %1\n"
"fstsw %%ax\n"
"sahf\n"
"jna 1f\n"
"fstp %1 ; |newVal| > oldMax; pop to oldMax\n"
"jmp 2f\n"
"1:\n"
"ffree %%st0\n"
"2:\n"
 : "=r"(newVal)
 : "r"(oldMax)
 : "%st0"
 );
```

Comment: I believe you may want to use `"=f"` and '"f"' in place of the `"r"`s that I have used, this would tell gcc to choose the floating point register for you. I'm not sure on the exact syntax for floating point registers in AT&T. Best of luck.